# ruby neo4j session persistence

Tags: ruby, neo4j

I'm using neo4j in a Ruby CLI app.

Each time a command is run from the command line, "session = Neo4j::Session.open(:server_db)" is re-established which is quite slow.

Is there anyway to persist the "session" first time use and re-use it in subsequent command invocations from the command line.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `neo4j-core` gem uses the `faraday` gem to make persistent HTTP connections.  That's defined here:

https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/blob/master/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_session.rb#L24

That uses the `NetHttpPersistent` Faraday adapter here:

https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http_persistent.rb

Which I believe uses the `net-http-persistent` library:
https://github.com/drbrain/net-http-persistent

When calling `open` on `Session`, you can pass in a second argument Hash of options.  You can specify a `connection` key in that hash which is a Faraday connection object which you've created.  That *might* allow you to save some token/string somewhere and the reload the Faraday object each time from that to pick up the session from where it left off.

The other option is to have a daemon in the background which has the connection open